# Error while uploading new app after deleting old app in store

Tags: ios, iphone, ipad, app-store-connect, bundle-identifier

I made iPhone app,

Now i want to upload my app on the app store, few days before i deleted my same app with same name from app store, and now i have created new app with same name

(**I have kept bundle ID same in both old and in new app**)

When i try to upload my new app in iTunesConnect it shows,

ERROR:

- bundle ID already beed used by diffrent software packages. even i have deleted my old App from the store.

Please help

Thanks in advance.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about iTunes Connect customer support.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't make a new app using an old bundle-id.
The only way is to make a new version of your past app. (You can still remove the previous app from the AppStore)

Think about it, one of your old user still have your past application on his device. If he download your new app, the old one will be erase of his device ...

Comment: But what if i want to use the same old app name ? with newly created app ?

Comment: Did you get an error by setting the same name to a new app with a new bundle id ?

Comment: If it's not your previous bundle id, maybe someone else is using it ?

Comment: If you have a bundle-id error, just check in your project.pbxproj and in your plist if you didn't forget to remove the old one somewhere